# Sqllite: How to add value into the table?

Tags: java, sqlite

I am going to write telegram bot by Java.
I received an entered row from user, and now I want to save splited row by words into the DB.
But I don't know how to add Strings directyly to the Value.
Can anyone describe how to do it right?

```
 default:
                        if (isAddClick==false){
                        run(message,ERROR_MESSAGE_TEXT,getMainMenu());
                        break;}
                        if (isAddClick==true) {
                            words=message.getText();
                            String[] splited = words.split("\\s+");
                            split_one=splited[0];
                            split_second=splited[1];
                            split_three=splited[2];
                            System.out.println(words);
                            System.out.println(split_one+' '+split_second+' '+split_three);
                            myDB = new SQLite();
                            String sql = "INSERT INTO ITEMS (PRICE,ITEM,QTY) " +
                    "VALUES (split_one, split_second, split_three);" ;
                            myDB.connectDB();
                            myDB.createDB();
                            myDB.insertDB(sql);
                            myDB.selectDB();

                            run(message,"Сохранить?"+isAddClick,getSaveMenu());
                            isAddClick=false;
                            break;
                        }
```

The answer is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: no such column: split_one
```

Comment: I understand that I shoud change the row "VALUES (split_one, split_second, split_three);" but don't understand how exactly

Comment: Look for Prepared Statements